# Unable to fetch a number from String

Tags: r, stringr

I have a Demographic column in a table like "Adults 18-34 Ethnic = Hispanic/All"I want to extract 18-34 age group from it.Can you please help? Preferably provide a solution with Stringr package.

Output should be like 
Demo
18-34
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub` from `base R`, we match the characters that are not a number (`[^0-9]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string or characters that start with a space followed by other characters and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^[^0-9]+|\\s+.*", "", str1)
#[1] "18-34"
```

---

Or using `str_extract` from `stringr` to match one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by `-` and one or more digits (`\\d+`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "\\d+-\\d+")
#[1] "18-34"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "Adults 18-34 Ethnic = Hispanic/All"
```

Answer (score 0):

First we can extract the numbers from a string, extract all numeric values and separate numbers using `-`:

**Input data**

```
str="Adults 18-34 Ethnic = Hispanic/All"
```

**Code**

```
paste(as.numeric(str_extract_all(str, "[0-9]+")[[1]]),collapse ="-")
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "18-34"
```